# change values in mysql trigger with php?

Tags: php, triggers, mysql

i've created `financialTrack` table in mysql, to log inserted rows in `financial` table, and then create this trigger to doing it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INS_after_financ 
AFTER INSERT ON `financial` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `financialTrack` (user, changedValue) VALUES (NEW.user, NEW.Value);
END;
```

these are my tables structure :

```
TABLE NAME:  financial
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| Column       | Type         | Null  | AI    |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| id           | int(10)      | FALSE | TRUE  |
| user         | VARCHAR(40)  | FALSE |       |
| Value        | BIGINT(12)   | FALSE |       |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+

TABLE NAME:  financialTrack
+--------------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
| Column       | Type         | Null  |   Def.Value     |
+--------------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
| user         | VARCHAR(40)  | FALSE |                 |
| changedValue | BIGINT(12)   | FALSE |                 |
| ts           | timestamp    | FALSE |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
+--------------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
```

do you have any suggestion to fill `user` field in `financialTrack` table with `PHP` script and remove user column from `financial` table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this task, but this lecture will surely help you to learn the basics of handling database queries with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.

PDO extension is currently quite popular and preferred over the other native `mysql` and `mysqli` extensions. You will find some other useful information by searching for `PDO` on stackoverflow.